# FInd overlapping values in two HoA

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array

I've got two HoAs that each contain 2 arrays as values. The following code sorts the first HoA first by it's key, and if the key is the same, then by it's the corresponding value for the first array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my @array1 = qw (1 1 1 4 5); # Note '1' appears several times
my @array2 = qw (10 45 2 1 6);
my @array3 = qw (a b c d e);

my %hash1;   
push @{$hash1{$array1[$_]}}, [ $array2[$_], $array3[$_] ] for 0 .. $#array1;

my @arrayA = qw (2 5 1 0 4); 
my @arrayB = qw (1 3 6 0 7); 
my @arrayC = qw (a z v i d);

my %hash2;   
push @{$hash2{$arrayA[$_]}}, [ $arrayB[$_], $arrayC[$_]] for 0 .. $#arrayA;

for my $key (sort keys %hash1) { 
    for my $value (sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @{ $hash1{$key} } ) {
        my ($arr2, $arr3) = @$value;
        print "$key: $arr2\t$arr3\n";
    }
}
```

I want to be able to perform the above function, but additionally compare values between (e.g. @array3 and @arrayC. If a value exists in both arrays, then I want to skip it, and print out key and values for each line 'unique' to that array.

Output for hash1 and hash2 (as it stands), with overlap between values denoted with `*`:

hash1

```
1: 2    c
1: 10   a *
1: 45   b
4: 1    d *
5: 6    e
```

hash2

```
0: 0    i
1: 6    v
2: 1    a *
4: 7    d *
5: 3    z
```

Desired output:
(removed lines that contain matching elements for array3 and arrayC)

```
0: 0    i
1: 2    c
1: 6    v
1: 45   b
5: 3    z
5: 6    e
```

i.e. removed:

```
1: 10   a
4: 1    d
```

from the first hash, and:

```
2: 1    a
4: 7    d
```

from the second

If I were comparing keys I would use:

```
for my $key (sort keys %hash1) {
    if (exists $hash1{$key}) {
    next;
    }
}
```

And if I were comparing two arrays I would use:

```
foreach (@array3) {
    if ($_~~ @arrayC) {
        next;
    }
}
```

How do I achieve the same thing for values in a HoAs?

Answer (score 1):

Because you want the output sorted from both hashes, I suggest you merge them. In that process, you can also throw out values that don't have unique keys.

For this to work as expected, we should create a set of last value items that occur in both hashes.

```
use List::MoreUtils 'uniq';

# build a hash of all common values for the last col, i.e.
# uniq $hash->{*}[*][1], where `*` would be a slice
my %last_col;
for my $hash (\%hash1, \%hash2) {
  $last_col{$_}++ for uniq map $_->[1], map @$_, values %$hash;
}
$last_col{$_} < 2 and delete $last_col{$_} for keys %last_col;
```

What we did there was equivalent to the intersection of the sets of last column values.
Now we can merge the two hashes, skipping when the last col is present in both.

```
my %merged;
for my $hash (\%hash1, \%hash2) {
  for my $key (keys %$hash) {
    push @{ $merged{$key} }, grep {not exists $last_col{$_->[1]} } @{ $hash->{$key} };
  }
}
```

All values are now merged, so let's print them out:

```
for my $key (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %merged) {
  for my $value (sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]}  @{ $merged{$key} }) {
    printf "%s: %s\n", $key, join "\t", @$value;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
0: 0    i
1: 2    c
1: 6    v
1: 45   b
5: 3    z
5: 6    e
```

To be exact, this *could* be pulled off without explicit merging, but that makes the code uneccessarily complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'll have a play around with it and let you know. From your point of view - am I using the right data structures for what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @FlyingFrog Yes, your data structures are allright, although I would consider encapsulating some operations inside classes.